# Perl creating class variable instead of instance variable

Tags: perl

I am trying to create variable which belongs to object (non static) not class. In my following code I tried some things.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Animal;

sub main{

    $animal1 = new Animal();
    $animal2 = new Animal();

    for (my $i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $animal1->next_move();
        $animal2->next_move();
    }
    print "\n";
}

main();
```

my animal class looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# 
# 
# Animal.pl

package Animal;

sub new
{
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {
        _MOVE => 0,
    };
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub next_move{
    $self->{_MOVE}++;
    print $self->{_MOVE}." ";
}

1;
```

my output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

while my expected out was

```
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9 10 10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change next_move to:

```
sub next_move{
    my ($self)=@_;
    $self->{_MOVE}++;
    print $self->{_MOVE}." ";
}
```

You would have caught this by using "use strict;" in your code.

Comment: Thank you. I just started learning Perl, didn't know about strict. Will use it from now on.

Comment: @Ruturaj: You must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program. The `-w` option on the command line (or the shebang line of the program file) is not best practice. You also need to declare all of your variables using `my` as close as possible to their first point of use. It is also preferable to use `++$self->{_MOVE}` instead of `$self->{_MOVE}++`. The name of the C++ programming language got everybody into bad habits!

Comment: I am using strict and warnings now. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You should use [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html).

You forgot to initialize the `$self` variable from the argument list in your method.

So, Perl just created a package variable called `$self` pointing to an anonymous hashref, and autovivified an entry `_MOVE` in that.

Also, don't use [indirect object notation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::Objects::ProhibitIndirectSyntax):

> The problem is that Perl needs to make a number of assumptions at compile time to disambiguate the first form, so it tends to be fragile and to produce hard-to-track-down bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend adding "use warnings; use strict;" to the code. 
Then do a perl -cw  to see if there are any errors.

Then you need to declare your $animal1 and $animal2 using "my", i.e. "my $animal1 = new Animal();"

Also, add my in front of "$self->{_MOVE}++;" in Animal-class.

Comment: If you include `use warnings`, then the `w` in `-cw` is unnecessary.